# What is a "catch block" in PHP?

Tags: java, php, class

I've been seeing code like this every now and then in PHP and I was wondering what's this all about.

```
$pdo = new PDO ($connect_string, $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    $pdo->exec ("QUERY WITH SYNTAX ERROR");
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What I'm interested is the `catch (PDOException $e)` code in general. 
I var_dump the exception and it returns the PDOException class ( doh.. logical ). But that doesn't clear things what's the idea behind this technique, why it's used and what's it's name :)

I've seen this technique in Java programming also but unfortunately I don't know Java very well... :/

Comment: PDO is configurable in that regard. You can also have it throw out oldschool PHP error messages instead if set to `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);`. It's just that exceptions and try/catch are preferred for business-critical data, and warnings are more meant for transitioning old codebases. (Though it's perfectly viable still for simplicity.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an exception handler to handle exceptions that have been thrown by `$pdo->exec()`.

When you execute `$pdo->exec()`, there are possible exceptions (the code not being to function as desired) that can occur, and they are *thrown* (with `throw new PDOException('error!')` or similiar). They will be thrown as far as the first catch of their specific type.

In the example above, your `catch() { ... }` block will catch exceptions of `PDOException`. If you didn't have that block, it will bubble up to any further exception handlers, and if not handled, will crash your application. You will see some applications that have a `try{ ... }/catch(){ ... }` block wrapping their main request, so unhandled exceptions will bubble all the way up to it (and be handled).

If you need to have clean up code or any code that must be ran in the event of the exception being caught, you *could* use `finally { ... }` (but [PHP at this stage does not support it](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32100)).

If you want to change the behaviour of the exception handler, you can use [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Comment: Ok that clears a bit thing. I've seen this also in other codes like this one `abstract class phpDataMapper_Adapter_PDO { public function read(phpDataMapper_Query $query) }` . Any ideas what's that all about ?

Comment: Kinda agree with you there, except that exceptions are not to be thought of as *non fatal errors*. They are exceptions, and they should be raised when an exceptional situation occurs. Exceptions **can be fatal**, even when caught.

Comment: @netcoder OK, I agree, I was trying to make an analogy but failed. I modified it, do you think it makes any sense now? :)

Comment: @The Devil: Look in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/abstract). Or post another question (please, please read the manual first!).

Answer (score 1):

It's an error handling mechanism. If something goes wrong, an exception is thrown (in this case the exception's class is called PDOException) and in the `catch` part of the code you deal with the error message and possible cleaning of mess that might have occurred in `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

you definetly should know something about OOP :)

This is the object oriented way of managing errors: in PHP (as in Java) unexpected situation (e.g. errors) are objects, exactly as anything else. 
When a method (name it methodA() ) call cause some unexpected situation, instead of returning false or just terminating the program an "exception is thrown". That means that the method is interrupted, the program flow is passed to the method/function that called the "methodA()" method which have two options: thowing itself the exception or managing it.
Tha catch keywork stands for the second way: When you write some code that can maybe cause unexpected behaviour you can surround  this code with a "try-catch" block, just like the example above: if the method call throw an exception object (of the type inside the catch clause) all the remaining code in the "try" block will be skipped and the code in the "catch" block will be executed. The remaining code will be executed as normal.

If you don't catch the exception you can run in different behaviour: in PHP it depends on your php.ini file, in JAVA it cause the program to end, in jsp the exception is shown in the screen and so on. Actually, in a production application you should ALWAYS catch exception when they may be thrown unless you're absolutely shure no exception will be raised.

just as a starting point have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: *rappresented* -> When Dr Dre is your lawyer.